# Space between closure symbols and terminal node of tableau in prooftrees.sty

Tags: spacing, logic, prooftrees

I tried to typeset a tableau with package `prooftrees` according to the package's documentation (cf. https://ctan.joethei.xyz/graphics/pgf/contrib/prooftrees/prooftrees.pdf) and Peter Smith's guide (cf. https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/L4LProoftrees.pdf). For me, there always appears an odd space between terminal nodes and the closure symbol. I tested the package with several TeX Live versions and the issue arises with TeX Live 2019 and newer. Would someone know a workaround?
Here some code I used:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}
  {
    close with={\ensuremath{\ast}}
  }
  [P \land (Q \lor \lnot R), checked
    [\lnot ((P \land Q) \land S), checked
      [\lnot (P \land S) \lor R, checked
        [\lnot\lnot S
          [P
            [Q \lor \lnot R, checked
              [\lnot (P \land Q), checked
                [\lnot P, close]
                [\lnot Q
                  [Q, close]
                  [\lnot R
                    [\lnot (P \land S), checked
                      [\lnot P, close]
                      [\lnot S, close]
                    ]
                    [R, close]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [\lnot S, close]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

And here the output:[image: tableau with weird spacing]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: As far as I can see, the change is between prooftrees version 0.6 (that's in TL 2018) and version 0.7 (that appeared in the lifespan of TL 2019 and is the current one).

Comment: And I have the feeling it's a wanted change

Comment: @egreg It's not wanted. Version 0.8 appears to fix it, but I've got a comment in the package indicating I'm not at all confident about the change. I think that's why I didn't push it to CTAN, but that's probably better if it solves an actual problem. Right now the change would set the distance to \baselineskip. Do you think it should be configurable?

Comment: @cfr I have the feeling that terminal nodes should be aligned, but I’m no expert in this matter.

Comment: @egreg Do you know any tableaux systems which require that? The ones I'm familiar with definitely don't and tableaux using those systems are not usually drawn that way. Neither Hodges nor Restall require alignment and Peter Smith made a couple of requests when using `prooftrees` for his textbook, but he didn't ask for that. (See https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/trees/ where he also mentions Jeffrey.) If somebody can point me to a system with that requirement, I could implement it as an option if `prooftrees` is otherwise suitable.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug introduced in version 0.7 and is fixed in version 0.8.

For the record, no system of tableaux proofs I'm familiar with aligns terminal nodes. So this is certainly **NOT** something `prooftrees` should or would do.

The erroneous spacing was a bug I failed to catch and certainly not by design.

Current output:

[image: revised prooftrees not displaying spacing bug]

for code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}
  {
    close with={\ensuremath{\ast}}
  }
  [P \land (Q \lor \lnot R), checked
    [\lnot ((P \land Q) \land S), checked
      [\lnot (P \land S) \lor R, checked
        [\lnot\lnot S
          [P
            [Q \lor \lnot R, checked
              [\lnot (P \land Q), checked
                [\lnot P, close]
                [\lnot Q
                  [Q, close]
                  [\lnot R
                    [\lnot (P \land S), checked
                      [\lnot P, close]
                      [\lnot S, close]
                    ]
                    [R, close]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [\lnot S, close]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```